# Numbers in array not being sorted numerically

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting

The program I am using is IBM Data Collection 6.0 (used to program surveys).

The issue I'm having is with how it is storing values for a question. The values for categories [1, 2, 3, 4, ... 59, 60] (numeric order) get labeled with values in a different order:

```
1
2
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
3
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
4
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
5
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
6
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
7
8
9
10
```

Can someone explain to me how this is being sorted and if there is an easy algorithm that would put it in numeric order?

Thanks!

Comment: Its being sorted in alphabetic order. Probably because the numbers are being treated as strings. Not sure how to do it in VBA but you need to make sure the numbers are treated as numbers when sorting. Oh wait, thats not even alphabetic order.

Comment: @dan08 The program is based off of VBA but really doesn't follow it that closely, so if you can figure out something in C++ or Java, I can just modify it. But yeah, it used to be sorted alphabetically, and then IBM applied some fix pack that caused it to start sorting this way and me and my coworker are trying to figure out the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

> > it used to be sorted alphabetically

add leading zeroes

this is just an example, may be it would help

```
Sub test()
    Dim Dic As Object:
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
    Dim n%, Key As Variant
    n = 1
    While n < 101
        Dic.Add Right("000" & n, 3), Nothing
        n = n + 1
    Wend
    For Each Key In Dic
        Debug.Print Key
    Next Key
End Sub
```

can be sorted as you need

```
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
008
009
010
011
012
013
014
015
...
```